# Create new columns in pandas to store separate values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
ID    onevalue  twovalue 
ABC   0.568      0.004
ABC   5.620     -2.514
ABC   -1.551    -0.452
LMN   14.56      7.456  
LMN   6.750      2.896         
LMN   5.620      1.166                   
LMN   8.640      3.486
```

Based on the dataframe above, i have the following function:

```
cond = (df.onevalue > df.twovalue)
df['S'] = np.where(cond, df.onevalue,"")
```

This works fine and gives me the appropriate 'onevalue' on a new 'S' dataframe/series.

What I am now trying to do is I want it to create multiple 'S' columns and put just single 'onevalue' variable per column for the given "ID". The column generation should restart after a new ID appears and that the repeated values should not count. Here's an intended result for clarification's sake:

```
ID    onevalue  twovalue    S      S1     S2
ABC   0.568      0.004    0.568
ABC   5.620     -2.514          5.620 
ABC   -1.551    -0.452
LMN   14.56      7.456    14.56
LMN   6.750      2.896          6.750
LMN   5.620      1.166                   
LMN   8.640      3.486                  8.640
```

Not sure if pandas allow undefined creation of columns, if that is the case we can assume a maximum of 7 columns per ID.

I have been trying to work my way around it but no luck. Little help will be appreciated.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can enumerate the rows with relative order within the `ID` and unstack:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame({'S':np.maximum(df.onevalue, df.twovalue),
              'idx': df.groupby('ID').cumcount()})
   .set_index('idx',append=True)['S']
   .unstack('idx').fillna('').add_prefix('S')
)
```

Output:

```
    ID  onevalue  twovalue     S0    S1     S2    S3
0  ABC     0.568     0.004  0.568                   
1  ABC     5.620    -2.514         5.62             
2  ABC    -1.551    -0.452              -0.452      
3  LMN    14.560     7.456  14.56                   
4  LMN     6.750     2.896         6.75             
5  LMN     5.620     1.166                5.62      
6  LMN     8.640     3.486                      8.64
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I avoid the repetition i.e. 5.62   I just want to keep the first one.

Comment: You can resolve with `duplicated` on the maximum series. However, one should be careful when checking for duplicates on floats since floating point errors can be a pain.